# CSS3 text-shadow effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I wanted to be able to create a effect identical to CSS3 text-shadow Property, making it available to browsers that doesn’t support this CSS3 Property (like IE 7 and 8).

And so I found two plugins: [Text Shadow](https://web.archive.org/web/20141108074018/http://www.hintzmann.dk:80/testcenter/js/jquery/textshadow/) and [Drop Shadow Effect](https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=limebits&e=com).

I decided to use Text Shadow, because it was released in the end of 2008, and because it was more straightforward.

This worked great for IE8. However in IE7 shadows have twice the distance to the text, and links are weird.

IE8 image
[image]

IE7 image
[alt text http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/2569/ie7.jpg](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/2569/ie7.jpg)

I am searching for a fix, or an alternative to this problem.

Comment: take a look at http://stansight.com/WordPress/2007/10/28/text-drop-shadows/

Comment: thank you for your effort anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own problem.

I used a pure JavaScript plugin called: [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

This plugin is very useful, because it makes old IE’s behave more like modern browsers.

Thank you all for your time and attention anyway.

Comment: I don't think this answers your question. ie7-js doesn't handle text-shadow.