# jquery.com's shadow effect

Tags: jquery, text, shadow

i cant figure out how www.jquery.com made their hover shadow effect on the secondary menu (Download, Documentation...". I thought it was a simple jquery plugin, but i cant find it anywhere.

I've found this: http://www.hintzmann.dk/testcenter/js/jquery/textshadow/, which is very straight forward, but (ofcourse) theres a problem with internet explorer. When the distance is set to 1px IE shows 2px... which makes it useless in my case

Im very interested in the jquery.com script..

(I've seen one solution for the 1px off in IE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678037/css3-text-shadow-effect-with-jquery), but im not very interested in using the mentioned script :(

Answer (score 0):

It's just CSS.  The text is repeated, once in white and once in black.  The black is underneath and offset by .1em

```
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com">
   <span class="jq-shadow">Documentation</span>
   <span>Documentation</span>
</a>

CSS:
#jq-secondaryNavigation li a span.jq-shadow {
   top: .1em;
   left: 1em;
   color: #131C25;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using $.fn.textDropShadow, which is a very simple function that adds a new element  on hover:

http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/scripts/custom.js

Comment: Are there any documentation for this script? I cant figure out how it works exactly

Answer (score 0):

Their CSS is defined as this:

```
#jq-secondaryNavigation li a span.jq-shadow, #jq-footerNavigation li a span.jq-shadow {
top: .1em;
left: 1em;
color: #131c25;
position: absolute;
display: none;
}
```

and they give the text the hover attribute here:

```
#jq-secondaryNavigation li a:hover span.jq-shadow
```